# Using RLS on secondary field to UserPrincipalName

Tags: powerbi, dax

So if I have three users: Tom, Dick, and Harry, and they have been assigned group colors.  I'd like them to be able to see everyone's data in their own group.

```
Name    Group   Email
-----   -----   -----
Tom     Green   t@acme.com
Dick    Red     d@acme.com
Harry   Red     h@acme.com
```

So I create a measure

```
RLS_SecurityKey = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(People[Group],People[Group]),     
    USERPRINCIPALNAME() = People[Email])
```

And when I log in as the separate users, I can see in a card visual that I'm getting the expected group.

But when I set row level security on the People table, `[Group] = [RLS_SecurityKey],` I only get back the one row that matches the email address and not the user that matches his Group.

It seems I'm missing something fairly apparent, but I can't see it.  How can I get back all the rows relating to Group and not the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it was pretty straight forward.

```
RLS_SecurityKey = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(People[Group],People[Group]),     
    FILTER(ALL('PEOPLE'),USERPRINCIPALNAME() = People[Email]))
```

I adjusted the filter expression and made it a proper filter over the whole table.